# Delete all pages (thousands) except a few by their IDs

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have over 20 thousand pages and need to delete all of them except very few.
Deleting them from the wp-admin page would take too long and a huge effort.
Is there a command I can run in PhpMyAdmin to do the job?

let's assume that I want to keep pages with ID (1,2,3) and delete the rest.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That would be SQL, which is off topic here.

Comment: Where to ask this question, please?

Comment: I'd use [wp-cli post delete](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/delete/) instead, since that delete things properly, tidying up comments etc. too. You can run this in batches with lots of post numbers, and use wp post list to fetch back the IDs to delete, and grep -v to filter out the ones you want to keep.

Comment: Definitely a use case for which wp-cli was designed.

Comment: @ Rup, @ jdm2112: How can I achieve that via wp-cli, please? can you give all commands required as I'm not too good at it? Thanks a lot, by the way, I can delete permanently with no problem including all posts too.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    $pages = get_posts([
        'post_type' => 'page', // get only pages
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // get all
        'post_status' => array_keys(get_post_statuses()), // all post statuses (publish, draft, private etc...)
        'post__not_in' => [8,18,15,16,17] // list of ids you want to exclude (pages not for deletion)
    ]);

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        wp_delete_post($page->ID); // delete page (moves to trash)
    }   
}
```

If you want something quick without working with wp-cli.

I use this sometimes when I need to delete something quickly and once.

You can put this code in your, `header.php` (will probably get flamed for this XD), and enter your site, this code will only execute for administrator level users.

It will retrieve all pages you want to delete and delete them.

In `post__not_in => [pages_ids_here]` put all the pages ids you DO NOT want to delete.

`wp_delete_post($page->ID)` will do a soft delete, move it to trash, if you want to delete the pages permanently the use this `wp_delete_post($page->ID, true)` (not recommended straight away because you will not have a way to restore them, unless you did a DB backup).

Before you run this code, check what $pages contains to see if you got the correct pages, once you are sure that those are the correct pages you can delete them.

If you can do a DB backup in case something went wrong.

After all pages were deleted remove this code immediately to prevent unwated pages deletion in the future.

Comment: With 20k pages this might get you an "out of memory" error. if you want to go this way you probably need to break it down to chunks and might even need to use cron to delete the chunks

Comment: ... at the very least you want to get only the post ids from `get_posts` and not the full post data. Even then your DB might time out, but this is harder to call.

Comment: ... and sending 20k delete requests under one http request by itself might end up being a problem and get you into php execution timeout

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, thanks a lot for posting the answer but i need to verify things first as Mark Kaplun said.

Comment: @@Mark Kaplun, thanks a lot, do you know a better way, please? even with wp-cli, i can use that too.

Comment: @MarkKaplun My bad, forgot to mention about the possibility of a timeout, what you can do is run 500 each time, try playing with those numbers. Again my solution is quick and dirty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @shireefkhatab wp-cli is probably the better tool as you are not restricted in memory and execution time when running it, but this is a valid answer just need to be careful about it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun can you post an answer for the wp-cli steps/commands, please?

Comment: @shireefkhatab sorry been a long while since I used it, maybe someone more familiar with it will come by

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to first empty trash, then trash the pages I want to keep, then via wp-cli I delete all pages permanently (skip the trash with --force flag)

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/delete/

then restore the few trashed pages.
hope that helps someone else.